# Como criar um Tema dinâmico com boas praticas para o meu Componente?

Tags: react, styled-components

Necessito criar um **tema dinâmico** para um determinado **componente** ou diversos outros, onde no mesmo utiliza-se **técnicas** de **clean code** e **boas práticas** referentes a **estruturação das pastas**, **separação de arquivos por tipos entre outros**.

Estou utilizando o [styled-component](https://www.styled-components.com/) **(esta tag não existe na comunidade brasileira**) para a estilização dos meus componentes, onde **nesta documentação** diz o seguinte sobre "[Theming](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming)":

**Theming:**

> O styled-components tem suporte total ao tema exportando um componente wrapper  . Esse componente fornece um tema para todos os componentes do React por trás da API de contexto. Na árvore de renderização, todos os componentes com estilo terão acesso ao tema fornecido, mesmo quando tiverem vários níveis de profundidade.
>
> **NOTA:**  retorna seus filhos ao renderizar, portanto, ele deve envolver apenas um único nó filho, pois ele pode ser usado como a raiz do método render () .

Para mais detalhes sobre o mesmo acesse [este link direto da documentação](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming)

**Quais são os meus problemas?**

- Dificuldade em integrar isto ao meu componente
- Dificuldade em fazer a integração utilizando todas as boas práticas de estruturação de pastas, separação de tipos de arquivos e funcionalidades

**NOTA:**

> Não possuo um código inicial para postar, pois como disse acima nos meus problemas estou com dificuldade em integrar o "Theming" do styled-componente com a lógica do React + ReactJS.

Comment: no meu projeto eu criei uma pasta chamada styles e lá coloquei os meus temas, pra integração vc apenas precisa coloca o seu componente principal por de um `ThemeProvider` no meu caso eu fiz no no componente `App` que é o componente que inicia tudo

Comment: Cara, eu uso o styled-components em todos os meus projetos com React. Olha um dos meus repositórios no github, e veja como trabalho nas estruturações de pastas: https://github.com/victorhermes/vuttr